# Concatenating some string elements in a list with a given string

Tags: python

I have a list of string as follows:

```
mylist = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

for a given string such as

```
x = '1'
```

I would like to have string concatenation of some elements in the `mylist` with a given string x.  I'm trying to create another list of logical index as follows:

```
ix = [False, True, False, True]
```

The expected output of concatenation should be the following

```
result = ['A', 'B1', 'C', 'D1']
```

May I know the pythonic way to make use of such logical index in order to get this result instead of looping?

Comment: Please try to do minimal research before posting questions. We don't like to encourage questions that don't demonstrate minimal efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to pair the value from the input list and your set of flags together, and use a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) in a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to do the concatenation based on the flags:

```
result = [value + x if flag else value for value, flag in zip(mylist, ix)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> mylist = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
>>> x = '1'
>>> ix = [False, True, False, True]
>>> [value + x if flag else value for value, flag in zip(mylist, ix)]
['A', 'B1', 'C', 'D1']
```